# If I run a SELECT after an INSERT in a PDO transaction, will my changes show?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, transactions

I haven't been able to find a simple and concise answer to this question so here goes:

I'm writing a PHP script which does two things:

1. A transaction with my DB starts using PDO;
2. Try catch begins
3. I insert a few thousands rows into a table using PDO
4. I do a SELECT on that same table and run a bunch of checks in PHP to find duplicates (if any there are) in a column
5. Finally I update the table to remove the duplicates.
6. If everything went OK, I do `$pdo->commit()`, if any error occurs the try/catch does a `$pdo->rollBack()`.

My question is:

**When I do my SELECT on step 4, will the returned data also include the rows I inserted previously in step 3**? In a non-transaction setting, I know it would, but since it's in a transaction, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't find an answer, test it yourself. Empirical evidence FTW.

```
mysql> create table mytable (id int primary key, msg text);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> insert into mytable values (1, 'foo');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> start transaction;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from mytable;
+----+------+
| id | msg  |
+----+------+
|  1 | foo  |
+----+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into mytable values (2, 'bar');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from mytable;
+----+------+
| id | msg  |
+----+------+
|  1 | foo  |
|  2 | bar  |
+----+------+
```

But in fact it is documented:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-consistent-read.html

> A consistent read means that InnoDB uses multi-versioning to present to a query a snapshot of the database at a point in time. The query sees the changes made by transactions that committed before that point in time, and no changes made by later or uncommitted transactions. The exception to this rule is that the query sees the changes made by earlier statements within the same transaction.